# Almost surely tends to problem

Tags: almost-everywhere

$\dfrac{\max|X_i|}{n}$ tends almost surely to $0$ where '$X_i$' has a distribution with finite $2$nd order moments. Can anyone here provide me with the proof?

Comment: Do you mean that ALL of the $X_i$ have bounded second order moments where there is a universal bound on the second moments, i.e. all second moments are less than $M$ for some $M > 0$?

Comment: Also, it would make it easier if all your $X_i$ were independent identically distributed. Is that the case?

Comment: yes and yes. the replies to both of your questions.
@user2566092

Comment: yes and yes.

the replies to both of your questions. @user2566092

Comment: We're here to provide you with help for your own learning and understanding (as opposed to providing you with proofs). What part of the problem are you stuck at? For starters, can you write down the definition of a sequence of random variables tending almost surely to $0$?